# Windows Forms - issues with showing a message from Message box

Tags: c#, winforms

I am building an application in Windows Forms. My problem is that in case "else" condition in the code below is executed it is not showing Message box as the code would imply.

```
else                  
 MessageBox.Show(this, "invalid username password")
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try 
    {  
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=192.168.6.51,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN; Database=INTIME; User Id=********; password=********";  
        con.Open();

        string str = "select * from Login_table where user_name='" + textBox1.Text + "' and password='" + textBox2.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        string login = textBox1.Text;
        string pwd = textBox2.Text;

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            if ((dr["user_name"].ToString() == login) && (dr["password"].ToString() == pwd))
            {
                Form2 objform1 = new Form2();
                objform1.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show(this, "invalid username password");
        }
        dr.Close();
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to remove the first argument from the call? Make it just `MessageBox.Show("invalid username password");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Else part is non-reachable***. You have passed userName and password to the stored procedure, so reader won't return any row if no user name with that password exist in table.

This check makes no sense because ***if data is returned that means this condition has evaluated out to be true already***:

```
if ((dr["user_name"].ToString() == login) && (dr["password"].ToString() == pwd))
```

You should ***show invalid UserName/Password only when no rows returned from SP*** :

```
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        Form2 objform1 = new Form2();
        objform1.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }

    if(!dr.HasRows)
    {
       MessageBox.Show(this, "invalid username password");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks :) Rohit Vats i'm Started C# First time. You saved my Time :)